# Why Whisper And Snapchat not working in genymotion?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I was trying out the new genymotion android emulator, but i'm not sure why snapchat and whisper apps not working in the emulator. I installed the ARM pack and gApps pack to, but i'm unable to make snapchat and whisper work!
Snapchat gets installed but won't work , Whisper also gets installed but we can't send message and post a whisper!